# Table Renders differently in Firefox than Chrome or Opera

Tags: html, css, html-table, cross-browser, tumblr

I'm working on a new Tumblr theme, and I'm having trouble with the audio posts. I put the information into a table, but the table is rendering very differently in Firefox vs. other browsers. I have the code here:

http://jsbin.com/iseqab/1

I would like the metadata information to either be centered next to the album art, or evenly spaced next to it. just something that will look good. chrome makes the last box (plays) take up the rest of the space. firefox gives each table row even space top and bottom. How do I get a consistent look between browsers?

Here is an image showing what I mean:

[image]

Comment: On my computer, Opera puts the top 3 lines close together, while the other browsers (Gecko, Chrome, IE) space all 4 lines evenly.

Comment: as the iframe and the descriptions are in the same table with different column, so the descriptions need to adjust their height according to the iframe's height. you may make another table in the 2nd column of first row and put the descriptions in that table, after which the height of description would be of normal height. i hope you understand what i mean to say.

Comment: Thanks for the tip Nitesh! That solved it. I have the revised code here: http://jsbin.com/iseqab/9/

Answer (score 0):

```
Use nested table in staid of rowspan as below. 

<table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td><table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
          <tr>
            <td><div class="glass" style="height:212px"> <img class="album" alt="album" src="Album%20Art%20Tumblr_files/tumblr_mp65f3F1nG1sxmxz6o1_1372533231_cover.jpg"> </div>
              <div id="audioplayer"> <span id="audio_player_54198232780">
                <div class="audio_player">
                  <iframe class="tumblr_audio_player tumblr_audio_player_54198232780" src="Album%20Art%20Tumblr_files/tumblr_mp65f3F1nG1sxmxz6.htm" allowtransparency="true" style="-webkit-transform: translate3d(0px, 0px, 0px);" frameborder="0" height="27" scrolling="no" width="207"> </iframe>
                </div>
                </span> </div></td>
          </tr>
        </table></td>
      <td align="left"><table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
          <tr>
            <td><table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
                <tbody>
                  <tr>
                    <th>Artist:</th>
                    <td>Julandrew</td>
                  </tr>
                  <tr>
                    <th>Album:</th>
                    <td>Songs To Dream By</td>
                  </tr>
                  <tr>
                    <th>Song:</th>
                    <td>Wait-a-little-longer</td>
                  </tr>
                  <tr>
                    <th>Plays:</th>
                    <td>4</td>
                  </tr>
                </tbody>
              </table></td>
          </tr>
        </table></td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```